# 401 unauthorized error when querying imgur api

Tags: ajax, http-status-code-401, imgur

I am trying to retrieve pictures from imgur to display on my blog by using an ajax request in jQuery

```
  $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "https://api.imgur.com/3/image/kvM6pxn.json",
      dataType: "jsonp",
      beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Client-ID <client-id>');
      },
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
```

but I am getting a 401 unauthorized error. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Looks like your request is cross domain. You can't use XHR type requests from a page served from your domain to request pages from another domain.

Comment: Ohhh duh, so how would I add the `Authorization` header? I already tried adding `headers: {'Authorization': 'Client-ID <client-id>'}` into the ajax function but that didn't work either.

Comment: You may be able to use CORS if the host supports it. Take a look at this article [link](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/05/25/cross-domain-ajax-with-cross-origin-resource-sharing/)http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/05/25/cross-domain-ajax-with-cross-origin-resource-sharing/

Answer (score 1):

Changing `dataType` from `jsonp` to `json` fixed it. Not really sure why though...